# Jira query to find TCs that are executed by specifin person (the assignee is diferrent person)

Tags: testing, jira, jira-agile

[Test Case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7sG5.png)

I want create a jql query to find the test cases that:

- are in one test plan and are passed or accepted
- and are **exeuted by** specific persons

For the first part i created the below query:

(issue in testPlanTests(NCB-78801) AND (cf[11812] = "NCB-78801 - PASS") OR (cf[11812] = "NCB-78801 - Accepted") )

But I cannot find a way to find the TCs that are executed by specific persons (the person that executed the TC is different from the person that is assigned)